# Ubuntu 19.04 - Hibernation does not work when lid is closed

Tags: 19.04, hibernate, lid

I think that I've tried everything and still hibernation does not work when the lid is closed. Well, the laptop hibernates after the lid is closed, but when I restart the system, Ubuntu does not keep the previous state.

I've tried the tutorial [Enabling Hibernate on Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo](https://outhereinthefield.wordpress.com/2019/05/21/enabling-hibernate-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo/), and when I execute

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

it works, but when I close lid it does not hibernate. Below is how my `logind.cong` looks:

```
NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

I do not know is it important, but on the same laptop I have Ubuntu and Windows installed.